# Asterisk reloads old dialplan

Tags: configuration, asterisk

I installed OpenBTS 2.6, Asterisk(not sure about version but it's not new) and Twinkle on Ubuntu 10.10.

I edited "sip.conf" and "extensions.conf" correctly to load user accounts from it.

Now, when I reload dialplan, it catches some old dialplan with macros I haven't use for months and they are erased from .conf files.
Same thing happens again and again. It's only type of file within Asterisk folder and I can't solve this.

If anyone know where from program loads that old dialplan and how to fix this thing, I would be grateful.
I tried to reboot and change usernames to root etc...no use.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Voice system engineer working with asterisk for several years. The configuration files are located at `/etc/asterisk` (I'm sure you know that)
Although I'm not familiar with "OpenBTS" you are most likely using some kind of Web interface (like FreePBX) and each time you modify (lets say `extensions.conf`) the webinterface will overwrite your files. 
Make sure your files are not modified by some WebUI or other simillar aplication.

Search in that direction.

Check cron... apache.... /var/www/... etc... 
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

go to asterisk by `asterisk -r` or `asterisk -vvvvvc` . Once you reached at cli console fire `sip reload` (for reloading sip.config) and `dialplan reload` (for reloading extensions.conf) . As in your case you can also `core reload` for reloading everything .  Once you have any doubt on saving dialplan that is every time loaded as per your old dialplan then you can add in extensions.conf [general]:

```
static=yes
```

{ if static=yes and writeprotect=no, you can save dialplan by
 CLI command "dialplan save" too }

```
dialplan save
```